# Google Apps Script DriveApp error when using File.getAccess()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have created a Google Docs add-on, which is deployed on G Suite Marketplace and uses the following code to detect if the currently signed in user is also owner of the edited document:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()).getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()) === DriveApp.Permission.OWNER;
```

This code works when run locally using Script Editor (both in G Suite and Gmail.com accounts) and also for users that are part of G Suite domain in which the add-on is developed. However, all other users experience the following generic error:

```
"service error: Drive"
```

The code is run after user trigger (opening of sidebar using `DocumentApp.getUi().getSidebar()` from add-on toolbar menu, which also asks user for necessary Drive/Docs API permissions).

Has anyone else experienced similar error, or is there a better way to detect if the add-on is being used by owner of the edited document?

Comment: Does this error happen with any other DriveApp method? Have you tried with the Drive API [Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method? You can compare the [owner's](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) email address with the getActiveUser one.

Comment: I'm not sure about other DriveApp methods, because this is the only one I use in the add-on. I've also checked Cloud Platform console and the add-on has the necessary OAuth scope for Drive included.

Unfortunately, comparing the owner's email address does not work, because the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() returns empty string for Gmail.com accounts.

Comment: I see. I recommend you to head over [GSuite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en), I cannot reproduce the issue.